# Suggestion of encrypt method for short fixed size result

Tags: encryption, cryptography, salt

I'm searching for a encrypt method that receives an int variable and outputs **exactly 11 hexadecimal digits**.

I'm starting on a existing application, that already has a database of more than 130.000 registers, each one with his own 11 hex-digits code. The old algorhythm only generated random 11 hex-digits, with no information codified. The new algorhythm should encrypt the id of a table *(int data type, 4 bytes)* into a 11 hex-dig. In case of collisions *(with old registers, that should be kept)*, I'm thinking of using a counter as "salt", combine it with the id I want to encrypt, and repeat incrementing the counter until it does not collide.

I have searched a lot these days about encrypt methods, symmetric and assymmetric methods, but all of them gives a result bigger than my limitation of 44 bits/11 hex-digits. I've also found that a so short cyphertext is not secure, but these data are not so critical and I can't change this limitation of the application, so it's fine.

Because I need to validate these codes in the future *(check if decrypted id is present on table, when datetime information indicates that it's a new-algorhythm code)*, I cannot take only a part of the cyphertext *(for example, using something like "LEFT(code, 11)")*.

The application runs on PHP/MySQL. Is there a encryption method that parametrizes the length of output? Or should I develop a custom encryption? In this case, any suggestion for avoiding collisions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hash plus lookup table?

Comment: Thanks for the hint, @schroeder. As English is not my language, I'm taking some time to research about possible solutions I find.  For hashing, wouldn't I lose some information? I mean, it's different of an encrypt, that can be reversible.

Comment: It sounds like _hashing_ would be more useful than _encrypting_ for that.

Comment: You are correct that hashing is not reversible, which is why you would need a lookup table to relate the hash to the data you need to relate it to. If you are limited to such a small set of characters, this is likely your best option.

Comment: I'm not finding good examples, it seems the term "lookup table" is more often used in image processing, both in English and Portuguese. Any suggestion of a good example I could read, or at least, another words I could use in searches?

Comment: A reference table, like a typical database relationship, where the hash is the unique key in the table and the record data is the data you are wanting to 'encode'. You 'Lookup' the hash in the table to learn what the hash means.